# dynamically resize flexslider carousel relative to window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

On page load, I want to dynamically size the slide so that the carousel underneath shows about 2/3, like in this picture:

[image]

I'm not really sure where to start. I've got something like this:

```
var os=$("#content").offset();  // #content is where the slider lives
var w=$(window).height();     // current 934, for example
var ch=140; // carousel height will always be 140px 

var used=os.top+ch;  // used 140+292= 492 height left

// what width will fit in 492px high and leave about 2/3 of the carousel visible?
```

One other thing: After the initial page load and re-sizing of the slider, the image needs to be dynamic if the page is resized.

flexslider init:

```
$('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
});

$('#carousel').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: true,
  slideshow: false,
  itemWidth: 210,
  itemMargin: 5,
  asNavFor: '#slider'
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a real working example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/65ht8b68/19/